# how to get notification if sent email is read by recepient and opened in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //please post the code to track email read by recipient
    }
```

i am working in asp.net.i m facing problem that i want to track a sent mail if a recepient is read or not.i searched many articles but  no articles are not given full ideas.is, anybody knows about this please post answer and your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
please post answers in asp.net
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it *is* possible although it's absolutely not reliable! Keep in mind that email itself is no reliable communication channel.

**Option 1** (unreliable):
You could add a read receipt to your emails as Harold suggested. Having that configured you can hope for your clients being willing to send those receipts at all...
Assuming they sent a receive receipt you could now somehow poll the mailbox of your sending mail account and check for incoming receipts. Alternatively (assuming you're using exchange) you could use **exchange web service** and subscribe to their push notifications (have a look [at this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa579617(v=exchg.140).aspx)). In this scenario you'll provide a callback service which ews calls on incoming mails.

**Option 2** (frowned):
You could send your mails as html and add e.g. a **Tracking Bug** 1*1 pixel image that signals your recipient having opened the mail. `<image src="http://yourserver/someHandler/?user=123" />` This *might be* a possible solution but note that you could get into severe legal problems as this scenario might create some issues regarding privacy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_Bug

Comment: Note that these "tracking bugs"  are the exact reason popular email clients like Outlook block online images by default, until the user explicitly unblocks them.

Comment: You can use a Mailing Service like  "Mailgun".
you can send email that attached to "Campagin" and the get statistics 
Such as "Opend,Clicked etc...).
They have Web api that you can use along with RestSharp for c#

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible with pure ASP.NET.

You can configure your e-mail client, like Outlook, to ask the recipient to approve sending the receipt. Or you can also configure the e-mail server to send the receipt automatically when a recipient opens the message.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for down voting. Is there a 'real' reliable solution using ASP.NET alone on the said problem?  What I offered on my answer above is simply the most commonly-used solution to get a notification from a client.